# Type {}[] not assignable to {}[]

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, typescript-typings

I am kinda new to TypeScript and I am struggling a bit to understand what's going on here.
The error is

> Type '({ flowItem: string; title: string; count: number; } | { flowItem: string; title: string; count: number; } | { flowItem: string; title: string; count: number; } | { flowItem: string; title: string; count: number; })[]' is not assignable to type 'DonutChartData[]'.

My DonutChartData interface looks like this:

```
export interface DonutChartData {
  flowItem: FlowItem;
  title: string;
  count: number;
}
```

and I am running a function to do some stuff like this:

```
const testnewGroups: DonutChartData[] = newGroups(data.productsCapacity, flowItem);
```

This `newGroups` function does some conditions and assign values to a object, and in the end of the function I transform this object into an array.

```
const newGroups = (validCapacities: CapacityItem[], flowItem: string) => {
const datesBreakpoint = {
    month: 30,
    trimester: 90,
    semester: 180,
};
const groups = {
    lessThanOneMonth: {
        flowItem,
        title: 'Less than 1 month',
        count: 0,
    },
    oneToThreeMonths: {
        flowItem,
        title: '1 - 3 months',
        count: 0,
    },
    threeToSixMonths: {
        flowItem,
        title: '3 - 6 months',
        count: 0,
    },
    sixPlus: {
        flowItem,
        title: '6+ months',
        count: 0,
    },
}
validCapacities.map((capacity) => {
    if (capacity.daysToWorkOffWIP < datesBreakpoint.month) {
        if (capacity.daysToWorkOffWIP < 0 || capacity.neglectedWIP) {
            groups.lessThanOneMonth.flowItem = FlowItem.uncategorized;
        }
        return groups.lessThanOneMonth.count++;
    } else {
         if (capacity.daysToWorkOffWIP >= datesBreakpoint.month) {
            if (capacity.daysToWorkOffWIP < datesBreakpoint.trimester) {
                return groups.oneToThreeMonths.count++;
            } else if (capacity.daysToWorkOffWIP < datesBreakpoint.semester){
                return groups.threeToSixMonths.count++;
            } else {
                return groups.sixPlus.count++;
            }
        }
        return groups.lessThanOneMonth.count++;
    }
})
const capacitiesWithData = Object.values(groups).filter(({ count }) => count > 0);
console.log({ capacitiesWithData }); <- it's an Array
return capacitiesWithData;
}
```

So, I am not sure what am I doing wrong here for it's saying it's not assignable to the DonutChartData type. How can I make it work?

Comment: The problem is variable `testnewGroups` expects the function to return a value of type `DonutChartData[]`, however, you are returning an array of a type other than `DonutChartData[]`.

Comment: `newGroups` gets `flowItem` as string and returns it as string, while `DonutChartData` need `flowItem` to be of type `FlowItem`

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova oh jezz! you are right, i missed this part. You wanna respond the question so I can mark it as correct?

Comment: TypeScript-wise: What is `CapacityItem` or `FlowItem`? what exactly does `data.productsCapacity` hold? The general problem of this snippet is that you are not typing your code sufficiently, except the function params. The comment `// <- it's an Array` at the end - is culprit - not only is it wrong (`capacitiesWithData` is actually of type any) but it also shows where your and TypeScript's thinking diverge. Start with typing your data and function return types, use an IDE to get inspection and find out problems in your code. JavaScript-wise: The result of `validCapacities.map` is ignored.

Comment: @vbotio glad it helped! Added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`flowItem: string; title: string; count: number;` cannot be assigned to `DonutChartData` because of the type mismatch - `flowItem: string` vs `flowItem: FlowItem;`